# Is it possible to read the contents of deleted folders in the RecyclingBin?

Tags: recycle-bin, powershell

I've been playing around with scripts that read deleted files from the recycling bin such as the one below but I can't figure out how to read the files within a deleted folder without restoring it first. I'm beginning to think it might not be possible. Perhaps running a SQL statement is the only way. Can someone confirm whether it is actually possible without resorting to SQL? As far as I can tell the recycling bin does not behave like a list.

```
$rowlimit = 5000;    
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sptest.com/ncart");    
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinQuery;    
$query.ItemState = "FirstStageRecycleBin";    
$query.RowLimit = $rowlimit;    
$itemcoll = $site.GetRecycleBinItems($query);    
foreach ($item in $itemcoll) {
       write-host -nonewline "Found " $item.Title " ... ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No - it is not possible to get content of a deleted folder.
Remains only two options (as You already mentioned):

1) restore items from recycle bin to the original location and examine;

2) get data from SQL directly, querying content DB tables [RecycleBin] and [AllDocs]